# How can I take a reference to a Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, reference, external, subroutine

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to make a reference to a subroutine in an external module file. Right now, I'm doing this:

External file

```
package settingsGeneral;    
sub printScreen {
    print $_[0];
}
```

Main

```
use settingsGeneral;    
my $printScreen = settingsGeneral::printScreen;
&$printScreen("test");
```

but this result into an error:
Can't use string ("1") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As noted in [perlmodlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html), you should start your module's name with an uppercase letter:

> Perl informally reserves lowercase module names for 'pragma' modules like `integer` and `strict`. Other modules normally begin with a capital letter and use mixed case with no underscores (need to be short and portable).

One way to call a sub defined in another package is to fully qualify that sub's name when you call it:

```
SettingsGeneral::printScreen "important message\n";
```

If all you want is a reference to `printScreen`, grab it with the backslash operator

```
my $subref = \&SettingsGeneral::printScreen;
```

and call it with one of

```
&$subref("one\n");
&{$subref}("two\n");
$subref->("three\n");
```

You could create an [alias](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) in your current package:

```
*printScreen = \&SettingsGeneral::printScreen;
printScreen("another urgent flash\n");
```

Skip the parentheses (necessary because the sub in the current package wasn't known at compile time) by writing:

```
use subs 'printScreen';
*printScreen = \&SettingsGeneral::printScreen;
printScreen "the sky is falling!\n";
```

The [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) module can do this custodial work for you:

**SettingsGeneral.pm:**

```
package SettingsGeneral;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT = qw/ printScreen /;

sub printScreen {
  print $_[0];
}

1;
```

**main:**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use SettingsGeneral;

printScreen "foo!\n";
```